# Calculating a vector space over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $A=\{\beta \in \mathbb F_{q^{2k}}: \beta - \beta^q \in \mathbb F_{q^2} \}$ be a subset of $\mathbb F_{q^{2k}}$.

Then $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb F_{q^{2k}}$ over $\mathbb F_{q^2}$.

So we can easily know that $|A| \ge q^2$. But I dont know the exact value of $|A|$ which means a cardinality of a set $A$. 
I tried to use a field norm and trace, but it can be helpful to know the case that the characteristic $p$ does not divide $k$.

How can I calculate the cardinality?

Comment: I guess $|A|=q^2$ but I'm not sure

Comment: Are you supposed to calculate the cardinality?  It looks like you're supposed to prove it's a subspace?

Comment: It is certainly a subspace over $\Bbb{F}_q$. Actually I'm not sure it will be subspace over $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ for it looks plausible that in some cases $|A|=q^3$. Gotta go now.

Comment: @Elizabeth S. Q. Goodman Yeah, I just tried to calculate the cardinality.

Comment: You can definitely show directly that it's closed under addition, because for $\alpha, \beta\in A$, $(\alpha+\beta)^q\equiv \alpha^q+\beta^q$ as all the other binomial coefficients are 0 mod $q$.

Comment: I'm finding scalar multiplication trickier.  $(c\beta)-(c\beta)^q = c(\beta-c^{q-1}\beta^q)$ so this seems to me to require showing that $c^{q-1}=1$ or that $(c^{q-1}-1)\beta^q\in F_{q^2}$.  I suppose this is what Jyrki meant that it's a subspace over $\mathbb F_q$, but there must be a way to use the $2^k$ and some group orders here.

Comment: Oh, $A$ is a vector space of $\mathbb F_q$ not $q^2$.Moreover, if $\beta \in \mathbb F_{q^{2k}} - \mathbb F_{q^2}$ and $\beta -\beta^q \in \mathbb F_{q^2}$, then $|A| = q^2$ when the characteristic $p$ of $\mathbb F_q$ does not divide $k$. I could show it, but the other case is open,

Comment: Correct @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman and PiggyJin. The image of $\phi(\beta)=\beta-\beta^q$ is the kernel of the trace from $\Bbb{F}_{q^{2k}}$ to $\Bbb{F}_q$. Here $\phi$ is linear over $\Bbb{F}_q$ (by Elizabeth's argument). Because $\Bbb{F}_q$ is the kernel of $\phi$, every element in the kernel of the trace occurs in the image of $\phi$ exactly $q$ times. So if all of $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ is in the kernel of the trace, then $|A|=q^3$. This happens when $p\mid k$, so in PiggyJin's open case we have $|A|=q^3$.